# Постоянная загрузка индекса IntelliSense

Tags: c#, intellisense

### Загрузка индекса IntelliSense для nuget.org

Обратил внимание, что при старте проекта Win Forms .Net framework все фоновые задачи успешно выполняются и заканчиваются, в то время как одна постоянно выполняется.

[image: с№]

Пробовал проверять пути пакетов загрузки NuGet в настройках. Все верно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключение к интернету есть. Пакеты по одному загружаются. Где посмотреть и что настроить, чтобы эта служба наконец выполнилась и не мозолила глаз?

Visual Studio Community 2019

Comment: какая версия студии?

Comment: 2019 Community.

Comment: А сами пробовали что? Или сразу вопросы задавать? Вот например [первая ссылка](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/754438/downloading-intellisense-index-for-nugetorg-visual.html) из гугла, которая имеет какое то решение. Если чуть углубиться в поисках, то пишут еще как минимум 3 решения - `Восстановить студию`, `Использовать VPN` ну и `Удалить из Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources nuget.org - перезапустить студию - подождать и добавить nuget.org обратно`.

Comment: спасибо EvgeniyZ, Ваш гугл определенно лучше ищет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [решению Lars Wilhelmsen](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/754438/downloading-intellisense-index-for-nugetorg-visual.html) и ответу [EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz):

1. Открываем реестр и создаем необходимые ключи в одном из каталогов (у меня это оказался второй - при создании в третьем не работает)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Перезапускаем студию
3. Проблема решена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]